# My site is not accessible to the DB .mdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, mdf

My asp.net is not accessing the `.mdf` database file.

Local site works but when you attach a server application is down when you click on the button (ADD/MYORDERS) that writes in the database (visit a link).
My site is hosted [HERE](http://testrs.e-animamundi.mk/(S(kkqkcog1pn02dzzpydeu1uo2))/StarterMeal.aspx)

This is the connection config:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the code of the button

```
protected void IB_ADDPred0_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    string insCmd = "Insert into Orders (RoomNo, ProductNo, ProductName, Price) values (@RoomNo, @ProductNo, @ProductName, @Price)";

    SqlCommand addOrder = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);

    addOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", computer_name[0].ToString());
    addOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNo", ProductNo0.Text);
    addOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", NamePred0.Text);
    addOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", PricePred0.Text);

    try
    {
        addOrder.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        Response.Write("Error. Try again.");
    }
}
```

Web application works normal when tested locally, but the server is the problems.

This is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: `LocalDB` is a **development-only** solution - it's **not** intended to be used in production environments, and it doesn't allow remote connections. You'll need to use **at least** SQL Server **Express** (and *enable remote connections* since those are **OFF** by default for Express) to host your database

Comment: _The application crashes_ do you have some more meaningful information than this? For example, instead of writing _Error Try Again_ could you print the exception message?

Comment: And to complete the observation from @marc_s about AddWithValue. You are passing a string in the value for the Price parameter and the AddWithValue takes the hint and creates a parameter of type nvarchar that is used to set the value for the Price field. Is the Price field a string?

Comment: Price is INT

Can something be make to not adapt the entire application?

Comment: This is my web.config 

`<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
         <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    
    
    </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
       </connectionStrings>
  `

Comment: Please remove 2 mb image from your demo web site landing page to make it browsable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem will solve at the if the make a web-hosting a new database and then Visual Studio just connect to it.

Download it from DDL current base and set of new to save time.

You probably use Windows hosting site. In parallels you can do it if the you create a [new](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GE77l0QRYnU) or [transfer](http://www.webfusion.co.uk/support/answers/how-do-i-create-a-mysql-database-on-my-dedicated-server-plesk-10-3174/) of old.